# How to read Python function documentation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem understanding some description of functions in Python.
I understand simply functions like `os.putenv(varname, value)` but I have no idea how to use this: `os.getenv(varname[, value])`. How to pass arguments to that function, what does those square brackets mean?

Comment: it means that the parameter between brackets may be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets typically mean that the value is optional. Here, `varname` refers to the environment variable you want to get and `value` is an optional value that is return if the environment variable doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets indicate the argument is *optional*. Read [the description](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getenv):

> Return the value of the environment variable *varname* if it exists, or *value* if it doesn’t. *value* defaults to `None`.

So you can call it like this:

```
os.getenv('NONEXISTANTVAR')
```

or like this:

```
os.getenv('NONEXISTANTVAR', u'my default')
```

This first is equivalent to `os.getenv('NONEXISTANTVAR', None)`. In the specific case of `getenv`, the second argument is returned if the environment variable doesn't exist.

Typically, the documentation will tell you the default value if you don't provide one, either explicitly in the description or by placing an `=somevalue` directly in the signature. If it doesn't indicate a specific value, then it will at least describe the difference in behavior.

[`unicode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) gives us an example of the `=` in the signature:

> `unicode`(object='')

Note that in Python, the only way for an argument to be optional is for it to have a default value.